# Undefined behavior when passing a pointer to a function with a formal parameter of pointer to const?

Tags: c, embedded, const-correctness

I have been working on some code that is similar to the following:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned char x;
    unsigned short y;
    unsigned char[NUM_DEFINED_ELSEWHERE];
} My_Struct;

static My_Struct my_useful_struct;   // Variables initialized elsewhere in code.

void myFunction(const My_Struct * p_my_struct)
{
    /* Performs various read-only actions utilizing p_my_struct. */
}

void myOtherFunction(void)
{
    static My_Struct * p_struct = &my_useful_struct;
    myFunction(p_struct);
}
```

My code compiles without any problems, but when reviewed I was told that unless I typecast p_struct that this could lead to undefined behavior on certain platforms (i.e. 8051).  However, I never even received a warning on the compiler.  **Is it true that not typecasting the pointer when passing it to the function with `(const My_Struct *)` could lead to undefined behavior?**

The reason that I declared the above function with a pointer to `const` was because I wanted to be able to handle both a pointer to const and a pointer.  **Is it bad coding practice not to typecast in the above situation?**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: (pedantic note: if it's undefined behaviour then it's undefined on all platforms, it just so happens that you get unlucky and it "works" on some)

Comment: Your code should not compile: `static My_Struct p_struct = &my_useful_struct;` is illegal. Only pointers can receive the address of something...

Comment: I think you messed up `myOtherFunction()` - you probably want `p_struct` to be a pointer and remove the `&` from the following invocation...

Comment: as @Christoph said, this shouldn't compile

Comment: @jupp0r: The `&` is not in the type name, it's in the initalization and hence the good old address-of operator.

Comment: Whoops... missed the asterisk.  Thanks!

Comment: @awoodland: Good call...

Comment: @embedded_guy: the example code is still broken - now you're passing a `**` to a function expecting a `*`

Comment: Every pointer type `T *` is implicitly convertible to `T const *`, so there is no need for a cast (and indeed this is perfectly logical).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is absolutely fine; the compiler performs an implicit conversion from `My_Struct *` to `const My_Struct *`. §6.3.2.3 of the C99 spec says:

> For any qualifier *q*, a pointer to a non-*q*-qualified type may be converted to a pointer to the *q*-qualified version of the type; the values stored in the original and converted pointers shall compare equal.

Furthermore, even if you declare the function with two inconsistent declarations, such that one file sees it declared like this:

```
void myFunction(My_Struct * p_my_struct);
```

even though it's actually defined like this:

```
void myFunction(const My_Struct * p_my_struct) { ... }
```

even that is allowed by the spec, even though the compiler doesn't know to perform an implicit conversion, because `My_Struct *` and `const My_Struct *` have the same representation (so the conversion is a no-op, anyway).

(Thanks to Christoph and awoodland for their comments clarifying the latter situation. In a previous version of this answer, I wrongly claimed that that *would* be undefined behavior.)

---

**Edited to add:** The reverse — defining a function with a declaration with a pointer-to-non-const parameter, but calling it using a declaration with a pointer-to-const parameter — is also allowed, for the same reason; but attempting to actually *modify* the data could well result in undefined behavior, depending on where it's from. (A `char *` can by initialized a string constant, for example, but it's undefined behavior to try to modify the data in that constant.)

Comment: actually, `My_Struct *` and `const My_Struct *` are *required* to be identical internally (see C99 6.2.5 §27), but as far as I know, you are correct that the two declarations are technically incompatible and using the wrong one is undefined behaviour...

Comment: So what is the solution, casting before calling the function?

Comment: @Christoph: no, that should be defined behavior, right? Given the incorrect prototype.

Comment: @jupp0r: Firstly -- Christoph means that the solution is: "using the correct prototype". Secondly -- given the incorrect prototype, an explicit cast wouldn't work, because if you explicitly cast it to a `const My_Struct *`, then the compiler will want to implicitly convert it right back to match the prototype! (And that implicit conversion is illegal, not to mention inadvisable.)

Comment: The example you give as not allowed *is* explicitly allowed - §6.7.5.3/15 explicitly says: *"In the determination of type
compatibility and of a composite type, each parameter declared with function or array
type is taken as having the adjusted type and each parameter declared with qualified type
is taken as having the unqualified version of its declared type"* (C99, I don't have a document for C11 to hand)

Comment: @awoodland: Oops. :-/ Thanks for the correction. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @ruakh: plus I don't see where that question mentioned translation unit.. trying to find one now ..; ok I removed mine, you can remove yours too

Comment: @Giorgi: The examples in that discussion, as I recall, were `strlen`, `strcpy`, etc. These are standard library functions. In the absence of a statement to the contrary, the only reasonable assumption is that their declarations are being `#include`-d into the translation unit using the appropriate standard headers. There is no doubt that this is what Keith Thompson's half of your conversation was about.

Answer (score 2):

Type casting constness onto or off of things is something I consider bad practice - there is generally nothing wrong with passing a non-const pointer into a function expecting a const one.

The exception is if there is some reason that the data can change part way through the execution (e.g. another thread touching the data pointed at) - then you might have a problem, but its not the sort of problem that typecasting will prevent. In this case you need to make your logic thread safe.

Don't forget that the const keyword can't be used by the compiler to guarantee constness either, although it can be used to detect problems where you think data should not change, but the compiler expects that you want to change it... its more of a documentation tool for you than anything else.

Comment: `const`-qualifying the pointed-to type makes absolutely *no guarantee* about mutability of the pointed-to object - it's purely syntactic, as adding a qualifier is an implicit conversion, whereas removing one is not...

Comment: [addendum] except when coupled with `restrict`, but even then only if the object is actually accessed...

Answer (score 1):

This works for me and I don't think the const pointer parameter yields undefined behavior, the compiler does an implicit conversion before calling the function:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned char x;
    unsigned short y;
    unsigned char[NUM_DEFINED_ELSEWHERE];
} My_Struct;

static My_Struct my_useful_struct;   // Variables initialized elsewhere in code.

void myFunction(const My_Struct * p_my_struct)
{
    /* Performs various read-only actions utilizing p_my_struct. */
}

void myOtherFunction(void)
{
    static My_Struct * p_struct = &my_useful_struct;
    myFunction(p_struct);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First I assume the `&` in the `myFunction(&p_struct)` call is a typo and what you really meant is `myFunction(p_struct)`.

```
static My_Struct * p_struct = &my_useful_struct;
myFunction(p_struct);
```

When you pass `p_struct` there is absolutely no reason to cast the `p_struct` pointer in the function call. This is perfectly valid to pass a pointer to `T` in a function where the parameter is pointer to `const T`.

In the C Standard this is ruled by the constraints of the assignment operator (C99, 6.5.16.1p1). In a function call of a function declared with a prototype, the arguments are converted as if by assignment to the type of the corresponding parameters (C99, 6.5.2.2p7).

Comment: is the other way defined behaviour? e.g. pass const char* to function needing char*? (assuming latter doesn't change the value where pointer points anyway)

Comment: @giorgi passing a `char *` to a function that takes `const char *` is not allowed, there is a constraint violation.

Comment: hm.. I was investigating this is some embedded code and even device manufacturers use a lot stuff like passing unsigned char pointers to functions expecting char pointers and vice versa - in their sample codes. If that is fine with them, I believe what I did in my above comment should also be ok? what is your opinion?

Comment: @giorgi of course I meant "passing a `const char *` to a function that takes `char *`" is not allowed, there is a constraint violation. Same for passing a `signed char *` to a function requiring an `unsigned char *`; in the latter case it's OK if you cast it, without cast your program is not a conforming program.

Comment: @ouah: Yeah there is no cast also but like i said the embedded device I work on has *lots of sample code* from manufacturers doing this ...

Comment: @giorgi and as they are not conforming program, some compilers will reject these programs. These programs are broken.

Comment: @giorgi if you want to extend that discussion I suggest you to open a new question